# Proving $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}- \frac{1}{z-1}$ is not holomorphic on $0<|z|<1/2$ (question is wrong f is indeed holomorphic)

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}- \frac{1}{z-1}$$ is not holomorphic on $0<|z|< 1/2$.

My original thought was to use Morera's theorem, to prove that $\oint_\gamma f \neq 0$ for some path $\gamma$. I tried $\gamma$ as the circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ and I got

\begin{align}
\oint_\gamma f = \oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z} - \oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z-1} =2\pi i -2\pi i=0
\end{align}

where each of the integrals is respectively $2\pi i$ as a result of cauchies integral theorem. Does anybody have a suggestion as to what path to try? Moreover, what is the intuition between the choice of this path?

Comment: What makes you believe that it isn't holomorphic on the given region?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos the question asked me to prove that it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But $f$ *is* holomorphic, since both $\frac1z$ and $\frac1{z-1}$ are holomorphic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Should I just assume that the question was wrong?

Comment: It is clearly wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mind me deleting the question so that somebody doesn't get accidentally confused whilst reading the title?

Comment: Yes, I do mind. You can always edit the title.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. I have done corrected the title as you have suggested. I believe what the person writing the question meant was that I should prove that it is not antidifferentiable rather than differentiable. Although I do not know if that is true or not.

Comment: That makes sense. The functon $f$ indeed has no antiderivative.

Comment: In regards to that what technique do you suggest I apply? I have dealt with the existance of primitives  for simply connected sets but I have never dealt with sets that are not simply connected.

Comment: I suggest that you post it as a new question.